# Upgrade LG V35 Thinq to Android 10

Tags: updates

According to [many](https://nerdschalk.com/lg-v35-update/) [sources](https://www.mylgphones.com/lg-v35-thinq-android-10-update-plan-q2-2020.html), Android 10 was released for the V35 earlier this year.

According to (the only US carrier for this phone) [AT&T's website](https://www.att.com/device-support/article/wireless/KM1269238/LG/LGLMV350), the most recent version for this phone is Android 10 at the May 2020 patch level. (Confusingly, that same page also says it is still only Android 9.)

However, my phone says it is on Android 9 with the July 2019 (!!) patches being the last that were applied, but when I check for updates, it says "Current software is up to date".

These updates appear to only be available from AT&T over-the-air, not from LG directly, and this phone no longer has service (I use it for app development and as a music player) so AT&T can't/won't help me.

Is there a way to update this phone?

Comment: This isn't the first time we read here about problems regarding of AT&T devices not receiving updates. Unfortunately from my perspective there are only two "solutions": 1. Get yourself an AT&T data plan and/or 2. Never again buy a branded device from AT&T.

Comment: @Robert I suspected that. Samsung phones on Verizon are the same. Apparently, just having AT&T service isn't enough - I put in a FreedomPop SIM card, which is actually AT&T service and says AT&T as the mobile network displayed on the phone, but AT&T apparently doesn't see that as enough. I will probably find a friend or neighbor with AT&T service and try to borrow their SIM card for a few minutes.

Comment: A Wifi hotspot (for connection sharing) opened by an AT&T device should be another option. That would enable you to use an AT&T network without having to get your hands on the SIM card.